# Device memory allocation fails on WSL2

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust, wsl-2

I am trying to run a simple c++ program, with Cuda Thrust functions, on WSL2. It seems that program fails in runtime to allocate device memory. I use Thrust with Microsoft visual studio all the time, and I don’t get any errors.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(proj LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)
 
add_executable(proj
proj.cu
)
```

proj.cu:

```
    #include<thrust/host_vector.h>
#include<thrust/device_vector.h>
#include<thrust/fill.h>

int main()
{
    //thrust::host_vector<int> h_vec(10);
    //thrust::fill(h_vec.begin(), h_vec.end(), 1);
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec(10);
    //thrust::fill(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end(), 1);
    
    
    return 1;
}
```

output:

```
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error'
  what():  get_max_shared_memory_per_block :failed to cudaGetDevice: unknown error
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I comment the device_vector line, and use the host vector instead, it runs with no errors.

Additional info:

- GeForce GTX 950M
- Windows 11 Home. build 22000.51.
- WSL2: Ubuntu-18.04
- Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85

Comment: WSL2 runs inside a virtual machine that actually probably doesn't have your GPU in it. Thus device_vector will not be able to allocate memory on the GPU - it doesn't exist in the context of WSL2

Comment: Does your WSL2 instance even have an access to the GPU? Try to check your device properties using code from here https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/how-query-device-properties-and-handle-errors-cuda-cc/

Comment: You have not set up CUDA on WSL2 properly.  See [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I post the question, I had already seen the instructions in [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html)  , and both downloaded and installed the CUDA driver for WSL, and joined the windows insider program and upgraded to windows 11 build. It did not work though.

But I also had Ubuntu 18.04 installed. I think it was installing Ubuntu 20.4 instead that made the program run without errors in the end!

So, this is what I did to solve this:

-installed Ubuntu 20.04 from Microsoft store (It asked me to download and run a WSL fix first, which I did)

-In powershell, I removed Ubuntu 18.04

```
wsl --unregister Ubuntu-18.04
```

Replace Ubuntu-18.04 with the name of your distribution. You can get its name in powershell by

```
wsl --list
```

-installed cmake and g++-9 (gcc-9 was already installed)

-downloaded the cuda toolkit using the instructions in [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html)

Then

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER=/usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin/nvcc  .. 
make
./proj
```